# How to vertically stack div elements from bottom to top?

Tags: html, css

I am trying to stack 2 `div`s on top of each other (that is, from bottom up).
The bottom one has dynamic height, I want the top div to be stacked on it accordingly.

*I want them to be from `bottom: 0` and up. not from up to bottom*

Comment: You could use flexbox. It depends on how much you care for broswer support.

Comment: this is html5 as far as I see... I need older IE unfortunately

Comment: In that case, it isn't reasonably possible. No.

Comment: Is there any reason why you can't change the order of the elements in the markup?

Answer (score 0):

`<div>`s are block level elements. They stack vertically by default.

Comment: Is that an answer or a comment? ;)

Comment: @Mr.Alien: It is an answer. I'm not asking the OP a question, I'm stating a fact.

Answer (score 0):

Using the Flexbox CSS properties is the only way to change the ordering of the elements in the way you desire (source order of elements is reversed from the desired display order, elements have dynamic sizes) if you're looking for a pure CSS solution.

If one element has a fixed size (such as an image, not recommended for text elements), you could use absolute positioning:

http://jsfiddle.net/wHDWP/

```
.container {
    position: relative;
}

.top {
    border: 1px solid red;
    position: absolute;
    bottom: 0;
    left: 0;
    right: 0;
    height:  1.5em;
}

.bottom {
    border: 1px solid blue;
    padding-bottom: 1.5em;
}
```

You could rearrange the elements using JS if you're desperate.